# GDB Cannot Set a Breakpoint on Shared Library

Tags: c, macos, debugging, gcc, gdb

I am trying to debug a program which loads a shared library. I can debug the main program parts perfectly but in the shared library, I run into some problems.

```
gdb -p 70876
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 70876
Reading symbols from /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres...done.
0x00007fff9496a2a2 in poll () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
(gdb) b multi_ProcessUtility
Breakpoint 1 at 0xdaa9: multi_ProcessUtility. (2 locations)
(gdb) b multi_utility.c:129
Cannot access memory at address 0xdaa9
(gdb)
```

So, the problem is that, I can set a breakpoint with the method name itself and the program stops at the specified point. However, I cannot set the breakpoint with the filename and line number. (The specified filename and line number also addresses the same function)

When the program stops in the shared library function, running `info source` command result with `No current source file.` message

At the time I have attached to the process, the shared library is loaded and running.

I am on Mac OS X El Capitan, using GNU GCC 6 and GDB 7.11.1 from homebrew. I have compiled both the main program and the shared library with "-Og -ggdb -g3" flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by downgrading to gdb 6.3.50.

Basically, I have installed gdb-apple from macports and it is based on gdb 6.3.50. I don't know whether it is related to gdb version or gdb-apple port has some tweaks that make it work.